# Is it possible to set or create a $scope variable after calling $location.path() on the page you are directing to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem. I am trying to implement a global search function on my website and am having some problem getting the data over. I have in one file:

```
/*index.html*/
<div ng-controller="ControllerOfFileIWantToGoTo">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="search"></input>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="searchValue(search);">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Inside the JS file with the controller "ControllerOfFileIWantToGoTo" I simply have:

```
/*FileIWantToGoTo.js*/
//$scope.search = ""; //I did not include this

console.log($scope.search);

$scope.searchValue = function(value){
    $location.path('/url');
    // Once loaded, do this
    $scope.search = value; //this never seems to get done
}
```

And the HTML associated with this page, has:

```
<!-- FileIWantToGoTo.html -->
<label>I am searching for {{search}}!</label>
```

Whenever I run this though, search is never updated. I do not set the $scope.search variable because I think any null value will overwrite the value I give it. It only navigates to the page an stops. How do I make it so that this can both navigate to the page AND update the "search" variable?

Also, I did try $apply(), but I received an error saying that it was already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *ngRoute* module and the `$routeProvider`

Add following to your app module to inject ngRoute

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Then create routes to your url and the controller

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/search/:searchParam', {
        template: '<label>I am searching for {{search}}</label>',
        controller: 'searchController'
    });
});
```

In your searchController you can access the paramater with $routeParams

```
myApp.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.search = $routeParams.searchParam || '<defaultSearchValue>';

}]);
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. $scope is relative
2. $locaton.path changes the location path and switches your context and thus your $scope.

I recommend setting the variable with a service. Both your controllers will need access to the service. Then inside your searchValue function, you will call that service to set the value and then redirect. On your results page, you can use the service to retrieve that value.